# Teleporting player object on collide not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to teleport my player to 0,1,0 on the coordinate system (right above the origin) when it hits any object with the "Death" tag.

Resetting the level works fine with this, but I want it to just teleport, so I tried this. I've searched many tutorials, but I just couldn't get this to work.

Any tips on what could be wrong?

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Death"))
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    }
}
```

(Note that the player just falls through the object right now)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using gravity on [Rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) component on your player object? turn it off and check the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, apparently there was some weird randomly assigned script that didn't exist on my death ground object.